# Understanding the gateway being 255.255.255.0

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

I know it looks similar to a lot of questions about OpenVPN and routing table, however, I believe it's different from the rest -- or at least I haven't found a duplicate yet.

In my case after I connect to the OpenVPN server, I notice that the default gateway is changed to 255.255.255.0 (that's right, the gateway, not the mask.) Below is my routing table.

Before connecting to the OpenVPN server:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.15.254   0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlp0s20f3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp0s20f3
172.16.8.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-8c249cf54f1c
```

After connecting to the OpenVPN server:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         172.16.15.254   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
10.8.0.0        255.255.255.0   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       255.255.255.0   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp0s20f3
172.16.8.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-8c249cf54f1c
192.168.100.0   255.255.255.0   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
_VPN_server_IP_ 172.16.15.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp0s20f3
255.255.255.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

It works as expected: OpenVPN routes all my internet traffic through the server, as well as all traffic to the remote LAN (192.168.100.0/24). It just confused the bejesus out of me when I saw the gateway to be 255.255.255.0. I would understand it if the netmask was 255.255.255.0, but it's the gateway set tp 255.255.255.0. How to understand this?

If I delete the first entry with `ip route del 0.0.0.0/1 via 255.255.255.0 dev tun0`, sure enough the internet stops routing through the VPN. I tried to play with it by adding back with

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via _VPNserver_IP_ dev tun0
```

or using the server's IP in the VPN subnet (10.8.0.0/24),

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0
```

neither works. So I suspect this is some kind of trick the OpenVPN uses to direct it to the server. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: It's certainly a typo in the configuration. But at the same time it doesn't matter: a layer 3 interface doesn't use a gateway, so whatever its value it's ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @A.B.  Can I understand it as that the line `0.0.0.0  255.255.255.0  128.0.0.0  UG  0  0    0  tun0` only says anything should go through the `tun0`? That said, how are the packets sent to `tun0` determined where to be sent next (i.e. to _VPN_server_IP_ in this case)? Is that part handled by OpenVPN internally instead of through the system routing table?

Comment: I just verified your comment above by changing the first and fourth entries' gateway to 0.0.0.0. It still routes everything to the OpenVPN server. Still, it would be nice if you could falsify/ verify my basic understanding of `tun0` in the last comment. @A.B

Comment: As you're already using `ip route` to change routes, you really should `ip route` to display routes. The (obsolete on Linux) tool `route` won't give all possible information. Beside this I didn't answer the question because I don't understand why when you delete then recreate a missing route it doesn't work anymore. You're not supposed to give a gateway at all on a layer 3 interface (which tun0 is else it should have been called tap0).

Answer (score 0):

As conjectured by @A.B, it is indeed due to a misconfiguration: I forgot to specify the topology as subnet, so it was defaulted to net30. As a result, in the log it showed this warning:

```
"Fri Apr 29 22:38:56 2022 WARNING: Since you are using --dev
 tun with a point-to-point topology, the second argument to 
--ifconfig must be an IP address.  You are using something 
(255.255.255.0) that looks more like a netmask. (silence this 
warning with --ifconfig-nowarn)".
```

After changing it to subnet it fixed the issue. This is what in my routing table the entries involving `tun0` look like:

```
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     10.8.0.1        255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
```